# Windows RDP (mstsc /prompt VS enablecredsspsupport:i:0)

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, rdp, remote-desktop-services, mstsc

I would like to know if the /prompt option of mstsc.exe is equivalent to using "enablecredsspsupport:i:0" in a .rdp file.

```
mstsc.exe /prompt
```

versus template.rdp with the following line (at the end):

```
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
```

Does both options have the same objective ?